# ajuda de retorno com Json

Tags: php, json

Como retornar array com estes resultados em php

```
 points 
 total  25779
 HTML   1793
 CSS    2666
 Design 216
 C# 0
 Databases  0

 $minhaarray [] = array(
        "points"=>$event->total,    
        "name"=>$category->name,
);
echo minhaarray ;
```

resultado obitido

```
   [{"points":"387","name":null},{"points":"1","name":null}, 
   {"points":"289","name":null},{"points":"1","name":null},
   {"points":"68","name":null},{"points":"290","name":null},
   {"points":"0","name":null},{"points":"116","name":null}]
```

Preciso deste resultado

```
   points :
  nome: 6548
  nome2:65774
  nome3:78587

 assim por diante

 igual a este resultado desta pagina https://teamtreehouse.com/ethanneff.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só precisa fazer isso daqui:

```html
$minhaarray['points'] = array(
        $category->name => $event->total 
);

echo json_encode($minhaarray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Mas, preste atenção aos valores `null`.